# No result when sending a mySql query in python3.7 with a group by

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, group-by, mysql-connector

I am facing an issue querying my mysql table in python3.7 (mysql-connector==2.2.9).
Here is my code:

```
import mysql.connector 

conn = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="127.0.0.1", 
    user="jeremy", 
    password="password", 
    database="facebook_messenger"
)

cursor = conn.cursor()

query = "SELECT title, uuid, sender, MIN(sent_at), MAX(sent_at) FROM messages GROUP BY title, uuid, sender;"
#query = "SELECT title, uuid, sender FROM messages;"
cursor.execute(query)
results = cursor.fetchall()
print(results)
```

I don't have any error but the results is [].

This is weird because if I run the same query right in my mysql it works.

Also, if I run a simple select (as commented in my code) I get the results.

My hypothesis then, it is that the group by does not work.

Any idea ?

Comment: Try giving aliases to aggregate `MIN` and `MAX` columns rather than leaving as expressions. Also, in your simple query, can you add `sent_at` column to receive results?

Comment: Yes a simple query such as `SELECT title, uuid, sender, sent_at FROM messages;` works. 
I tried with alias: 
`query = "SELECT title, uuid, sender, min(%s), max(%s) FROM messages GROUP BY title, uuid, sender;"`
`adr = ("sent_at", "sent_at")`
`cursor.execute(query, adr)`

I still have no result.

Comment: I meant SQL aliases using `AS` operator: `...MIN(sent_at) AS min_sent_at, MAX(sent_at) AS max_sent_at...`

Comment: I found what the issue was. In Python I need to add `where sender <> '' and title <> ''` where in my mysql client I don't need that to get results.
Thanks! :)

Comment: Very odd! I cannot see why that's the issue. Be sure to use latest versions of modules. Even report buggy items like that to package authors. Alternatively consider `pymysql`.